# iPhone: call JS function

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

in webViewDidFinishLoad: I have a code:

```
NSString *functionCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setString(%@)", @"string"];
[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:functionCall];
```

And in Java Script:

```
function setString(string) {
    alert(string);
}
```

but I dont see alert when webView finished load...What I do wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to invoke an Objective-C method. You have to pass javascript code to the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method.

What you likely want to do is something like this:

```
NSString *functionCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert('%@');", @"string"];

[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:functionCall];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting quotation marks:

```
NSString *functionCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setString('%@')", @"string"];
[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:functionCall];
```